# Simplifying quotient of infinite series with positive and negative powers

Tags: polynomials

I have a function that is defined as the quotient of two infinite sums, but here is the problem: at the numerator I only have (almost) negative powers, such as $1/2$ (this is the only positive), $-1/2$, $-3/2$, $-5/2$ and so on... But at the denominator, I have negative and positive powers ($-1/2$, $-3/2$, $-5/2$... and also $1/2$, $3/2$, $5/2$...).

$$f(x)=\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} g_n \, x^{(1-2n)/2}}{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} h_n^+ \, x^{(2n-1)/2}+h_n^- \, x^{(1-2n)/2}}$$

where $g_n$, $h_n^+$ and $h_n^-$ are the coefficients related to the n-th term. They can be treated as numbers.

Is there a way to simplify this function, or at least to compute efficiently some terms?

Edit: Thanks to @MPW, we can avoid to have non-integers powers of $x$ by factoring by $x^{-1/2}$, that gives us:

$$f(x)=\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} g_n \, x^{-n}}{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}h_n^+ \, x^{n-1}+h_n^- \, x^{-n}}$$

Once I got here, how can I continue if I want to compute some values of my function?

Comment: If you factor $x^{1/2}$ (or, $x^{-1/2}$ if that's better) out of the sums, the powers of $x$ are all integers, right?

Comment: @MPW you're right, thanks. It's done... If you have another clue for the rest, I'll glad to hear it too.

Comment: It would help if you could specify what $~g_n, ~h_n^+, ~$ and $~h_n^- ~$ refer to.

Comment: @user2661923 They are the coefficients related to the n-th term of the sum. I can compute their value, but cannot have the formula.